# Prevent apache from running python script

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, cgi

I wanted to host a `.py` file on my website, for download, but instead Apache runs it as a CGI script.

If I don't have executable flag on it, I get an error 500.

Is there any way to disable running of this file, maybe with **htaccess**?
I don't have full control over the machine, so can't alter apache config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derp, found it

Solution is to put this in a `.htaccess` where I want to block it:

```
RemoveHandler .cgi .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml .pl .py .pyc .pyo
```